# Rounding corners of pictures with ImageMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, image-manipulation, imagemagick

in my Rails app I want to have a similar profile section like Facebook where uploaded images are automatically thumbnailed and corner-rounded. I'm using the `convert` utility to downsize images into thumbnails, but is there an option to round their corners too? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some rounded corners examples: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#rounded_border.  You'll need to create a mask of some sort (either by hand or using the drawing tools) and then overlay it onto your image.

Comment: Are there any jQuery plugins to automagically do this, or is that just wishful thinking?

Comment: This page gives an example of using the jquery corners plugin on an image: 
http://www.malsup.com/jquery/corner/image.html

It's referencing the plugin from here: http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/plugins/corner/jquery.corner.js

Answer (score 28):

**Universal solution**

This solution works with transparent and non-transparent pictures. To add 15 pixels radius rounded corners to `original_picture.png` which is a 100x100 picture:

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:none -draw "roundrectangle 0,0,100,100,15,15" mask.png
convert original_picture.png -matte mask.png \
  -compose DstIn -composite picture_with_rounded_corners.png
```

This solution was given by [PM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/233099/pm) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1916256/499917

**Elegant solution, does not work with transparent pictures**

This solution works without any intermediate picture. How nice! But it will disrupt your original picture's transparency. So use only when you are sure that your picture is not transparent.

Suppose you want rounded corners with 15px radius:

```
convert original_picture.png \
  \( +clone  -alpha extract \
    -draw 'fill black polygon 0,0 0,15 15,0 fill white circle 15,15 15,0' \
    \( +clone -flip \) -compose Multiply -composite \
    \( +clone -flop \) -compose Multiply -composite \
  \) -alpha off -compose CopyOpacity -composite picture_with_rounded_corners.png
```

For convenience, here is what you will typically do in Ruby or some other languages:

```
in_pic = "original_picture.png"
out_pic = "picture_with_rounded_corners.png"
radius = 15
cmd = "convert #{in_pic} \\( +clone  -alpha extract " +
        "-draw 'fill black polygon 0,0 0,#{radius} #{radius},0 fill white circle #{radius},#{radius} #{radius},0' " +
        "\\( +clone -flip \\) -compose Multiply -composite " +
        "\\( +clone -flop \\) -compose Multiply -composite " +
        "\\) -alpha off -compose CopyOpacity -composite #{out_pic}"
`#{cmd}`
```

Source: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#rounded

Comment: When I try the command line version (on Windows 7 box), the bottom right corner of "mask.png" is off.  To fix, I had to remove 1 pixel from the -draw argument, like: convert -size 100x100 xc:none -draw "roundrectangle 0,0,99,99,15,15" mask.png

Comment: For me, the mask only covers the left-top corner of the initial picture and it's really small. Changing the size of the mask makes the cutout bigger, but it still has the same left-top corner. Any help?

Answer (score 7):

Facebook doesn't modify pictures to have rounded corners. Instead, they use HTML and CSS to apply this image over each user picture: http://www.facebook.com/images/ui/UIRoundedImage.png

If you inspect `UIRoundedImage.png`, you'll find that each "square" consists of a transparent center, and opaque corners that are meant to match the background on which the user picture will rest. For instance, if the user picture is on a white background, then white opaque rounded corners will be overlaid on the user picture.

The CSS technique for using just a specific part of `UIRoundedImage.png` is called "CSS sprites". You can read more about it here: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites/