# Rounded corners using ImageMagick (bakground transparent or white)

Tags: imagemagick, rounded-corners

I'm trying to add rounded corners to my images using ImageMagick.

If the input image is a PNG or GIF file my script is working correctly.

But if my input file is a JPEG file, the corners are black. I'd like to use a custom corner color in that case (ex. white) any idea ?

Here's my working bash script :

```
convert -size "$W"x"$H" xc:none -draw "roundrectangle 0,0,$W,$H,$R,$R" $MASK
convert $SRC -matte $MASK -compose DstIn -composite $DST
```

Parameters are :

$SRC : the input image
$W : width of input image
$H : height of input image
$MASK : the mask image which contains transparent corners
$DST : the resulting image with rounded corners.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

Finally found a solution :

```
convert -size "$W"x"$H" xc:none -draw "roundrectangle 0,0,$W,$H,$R,$R" $MASK
convert $SRC -matte $MASK -compose DstIn -composite $TMP_PNG
```

I'm using a "temp" PNG file as destination. If the output format is not GIF or PNG, I use the "flatten" function of ImageMagick with the white color as background.

```
convert $TMP_PNG -background white -flatten $DST
```

For PNG output : simply copy $TMP_PNG to $DST

For GIF output : simply convert $TMP_PNG to $DST

Else : flatten the image as said before.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Note for anyone reading this answer: if the temporary mask file `$TMP_PNG` doesn't have a file extension that identifies its format (e.g `.png`) then you need to prefix the variable with it instead. Like this: `png:$TMP_PNG`. Also `canvas:none` is the new way of writing `xc:none` althugh the latter still works.